# Need to tweak an abandoned plugin for my use

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using [WPMUDEV's BuddyPress Group Calendar](https://github.com/wpmudev/bp-group-calendar) for a project, and as it's no longer supported, am trying to find help in making it do what I need. Basically, I need a way to assign an event to a group member and while the @username function works, it send no alert or any notification of any kind to the "assigned" person.

I would like to make a member's list drop-down menu to select the assigned member and then have them notified of the event post.

If there's anyone who has insight into how to go about this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with WPMUDEV company once, and we were supporting all the legacy plugins, the company terms says that WPMUDEV supports all plugins but for the legacy plugins they stopped developing them. 
However, you can go to there forum and ask them or talk to them by he Live Chat for support.